# proving a binary relation on $\mathbb{Z} × \mathbb{Z}$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Define a binary relation ∼ on $\mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{Z}$ by $(a, b) ∼ (c, d)$ if and only if $ad = bc$.

Prove that ∼ is an equivalence relation.

I'm trying to prove symmetric of this relation. Do I just show that $ab=bc$ and $bc=ab$ are equivalent by commutative property? how can I prove it?

Comment: You have to show that $(a_1,a_2)\sim(b_1,b_2)\implies (b_1,b_2)\sim(a_1,a_2)$, Now $(a_1,a_2)\sim(b_1,b_2)\implies a_1b_2=a_2b_1$,We have to show $b_1a_2=b_2a_1$.Which is true by commutativity of reals.

Comment: @PNDas got it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that $(a_1,a_2)\sim(b_1,b_2)\implies (b_1,b_2)\sim(a_1,a_2)$.

Now $$(a_1,a_2)\sim(b_1,b_2)\\\implies a_1b_2=a_2b_1\\\implies a_2b_1=a_1b_2\;\;\text{,since '=' is symmetric}\\\implies b_1a_2=b_2a_1\;\;\text{,since multiplication is commutative for reals}\\\implies (b_1,b_2)\sim(a_1,a_2)\,\,\square$$

Comment: so it would be same even though second pair is just $\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Z} - 0$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'second pair is just $\mathbb{Z}'$.

Comment: don't we need to think about when second pair is $0$ also? since it's $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It'll not make any difference .If we write $(b_1,b_2)=(0,0)$ then the result is still valid.

Comment: oh okay. then, I guess transitivity would be also same?